# Javascript date formats customizing

Tags: javascript, postman

I'm trying to test an API to check if the dates are present in the comment. The date is given in ISO format in the comment like 2020-02-18 21:30:13

When I compare with the Date() and convert it to ISO format, the format is slightly different from my date which makes my test to fail. How do I make the format the same as the one is my API response?

Below is my code:

```
  var dateobj = new Date();
var B = dateobj.toISOString();
pm.test("Comment has Date", function (){
    pm.expect(responseBody.split("*/")[0]).to.include(B)
})
```

Comment: Try and compare using the Date format generated from my answer below and provide feedback?

Answer (score 1):

**Something Like This?**

Javascript is not very flexible with Dates. But I think creating a formatting function shouldn't be a problem at all, try this:

```js
var date = new Date();

var formattedDate = (date)=>{
  return (`${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth()}-${date.getDay()} ${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}:${date.getSeconds()}`);
}

alert(formattedDate(date));
```